# Node.js - Nested array in Jade view

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

Using Mongoose, I have a model Page with an embedded model of Feeds. When i go to /pages, the page.title shows up for each page, but feeds data does not. how should i modify this code to properly display the data from the feeds array?  thanks a million

db.pages exmaple:

```
{ "title" : "testing feeds", "_id" : ObjectId("123456"), "feeds" : [
{ "0" : { "name" : "twitter", "key" : "1234" },
  "1" : { "name" : "flickr", "key" : "5678" },
}] }
```

web.js

```
app.get('/pages.:format?', function(req, res) {
  Page.find({}, function(err, pages) {
    switch (req.params.format) {
      case 'json':
        res.send(pages.map(function(d) {
          return d.toObject();
        }));
      break;

      default:
        res.render('pages/index.jade', {
          locals: { 
              title: 'ClrTouch | Pages',
              pages: pages,
              feeds: pages.feed,
          }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

view

```
- each page in pages
  div.page
    div.pagetitle= page.title
      ul
      - each feed in page.feeds
        li.pagefeedname= feed.name
        li.pagefeedkey= feed.key
```

with what i have, a list is generated in the view but the list items are empty.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the model that you have here what you are also testing with? If so, then the reason your list is generated but nothing is displayed is because you do not currently have values in either.

`li.pagefeedname=feed.name` = "0" : { **"name" : ""**, "key" : "" }

Try giving your feed name/keys some values and see how that plays out.

Otherwise what you have should work

Comment: ugh that was my bad, just edited the db sample. not getting feeds data to the view. in the referenced example, the `page.title` would render but not the feeds. a ul with lis will show up but won't have data.

Comment: hmm so yeah, that's not working. if i request the page at /pages.json I successfully get a full copy of the json with the feeds data, i'm just not getting it to come out in the html view...

Answer (score 0):

tuddy,
  I suggest you try like this:

```
   Page.find().lean().exec(function(err,pages){
   // TODO
  });
```